# Shortcut to save a document?

Tags: web-app, save, keyboard-shortcuts

With the *offline* programs the convention (at least in English) is to type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save a document. However, in many online web(app)s the convention is to type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to submit the current form, normally used for comments. However, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> might be used to NOT submit a form.

The thing is quite complicated, and it highly depends on each page to provide a shortcut for submitting the current form. This is okay in empty `<textarea>`s since they can provide a placeholder to explain this, but not so much when editing. So the question is:

**Is the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> shortcut still relevant for websites when *editing* a document such as a blog post or other long texts?** (overwriting the 'save this page' functionality)

Comment: What website are you using? I think your question is website specific

Comment: Why not use Autosave?

Comment: Autosave is a good idea, also once you start messing with browser shortcuts, you start detracting from the user experience.

Comment: I am not thinking of a website specific site, I am trying to find if there's a common used 'standard' for saving websites as there is in programs.
Autosave was considered, but it's not always applicable (and in this case it's not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find this information helpful:

- Wordpress uses Ctrl+S to save a draft when creating or editing a post.
- According to https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/42197?hl=en, Blogger uses Ctrl+s to "Autosave and keep editing"
- A quick google search of "ctrl s WYSIWYG" reveals that other WYSIWYG editors also use this functionality

I'm giving no opinion here as to whether this is a good idea, but it seems that ctrl+S is at least somewhat common for saving forms in web based applications.